# Nvidia X driver fails to install

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-current-dev

My laptop is the Acer Timeline Ultra M5-481TG. It has an Nvidia Geforce GT 640M LE gpu. I am running Ubuntu Studio 12.10.

I have tried to install this driver many ways because Nouveau eats my battery and I believe is somewhat out of date. I have even tried using `sudo stop lightdm` in another console. I have tried `nvidia-current`, `nvidia-current-updates`, `nvidia-experimental-310`, and the `.run` file of their website. Every time I open `nvidia-settings` it tells me to run the `nvidia-xconfig'` as **root** then restart X. I tried this both in X and with X stopped in an alternate console. I have also installed `bumblebee` and that did nothing to get the Nvidia X Driver running. I installed `jockey-common` as well and enabled these drivers using it, but again to no avail. When I run `nvidia-xconfig` it does create the necessary changes to the config file, but these don't result in it actually running or resolving the error. I have read very many articles and tried so many things. i.e. `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` and of course `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, and `apt-get dist-upgrade`. I have purged and reinstalled everything in numerous ways looking for just the right combination, no luck thus far.

This has eaten hours of my time! Please help and thanks!

Edit:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-common nvidia-current nvidia-settings && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install nvidia-common nvidia-current nvidia-settings && sudo jockey-text -e kmod:nvidia_current && sudo nvidia-xconfig && sudo restart lightdm
```

I made a "meta"-command for lulz and to give it one last shot. Still no luck.

Comment: On another forum someone told me this: "Remove any proprietary nvidia driver you tried to install and then:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee"

Comment: I tried it without success and replied: "I removed nvidia-current, nvidia-common, and nvidia-settings with the synaptic package manager then followed the bumblebee instructions step by step. These instructions ended up asking me to reinstall so I did at the appropriate time. After a reboot nothing changed and my resolution is still horribly dystopic....

Comment: So I tried a couple other things. Bumblebee makes it impossible to run nvidia-xconfig; when run it displays an error saying package is not found even though nvidia-settings says to run it as root still. I still cannot find it in additional drivers and sudo jockey-text -e kmod:nvidia_current said driver could not be installed. I also edited the xorg file related to bumblebee and pointed it to the nvidia driver instead of nouveau, although maybe I did this step wrong....

Comment: Please see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2119067. Askubuntu limits post length, but I have put some more information up there which may be valuable.